# How do I verify in .NET a file's signature if it is stored in system's catalogs store?

Tags: .net, windows, digital-signature, digital-certificate

For embedded signatures I can use X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile to extract the certificate. 
For catalog signatures, in C/C++, I can use CryptCATAdminEnumCatalogFromHash to do the same thing. What is the .Net way to extract the certificate for a file in the system's store?